# VSCode TypeScript Map get is still considered undefined even with a has check before

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

If I defined a simple Map with:
`const map = new Map<string, string>();`
and later want to do something with it I would expect this to work:

```
if (map.has(key)) {
    const value = map.get(key);
    // do something with it
}
```

But VSCode gives me this error for `get`:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

So I have to revert to this:

```
const value = map.get(key);
if (value) {
    // do something with it
}
```

This just doesn't feel right and makes the `has` method almost useless.
Is this a TypeScript problem or a VSCode Problem?

Comment: Even without TypeScript, I really prefer your second version - that way you only have to interface with the Map once, rather than call something in it twice.

Comment: Yep. In TS, where we can be pretty sure that we didn't accidentally set a key to null, undefined or some other falsey value, your second version is all we really need.

Comment: @CertainPerformance maybe this is just my Java background coming through where you have to use the first pattern to prevent NPEs.

Comment: ...although, dependent on what strings you put in your map, you might prefer a more robust check than `if(value){...`, because `""` (the empty string) is falsey, which *might* lead to a bit of head-scratching.

Comment: @spender that is just a simplified example, my actual values are instances of classes and not primitives'. The number 0 would also be evaluated as false.